# Data structure - Shifting IDs to next dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I have Date and ID.

[image]

```
Created the dataset using the following code

import pandas as pd

# Function to generate the specified dataset
def generate_dataset():
    data = {
        'Date': ['09-03-2024']*7 + ['10-03-2024']*4,
        'ID': [f'ID_{i}' for i in range(1, 12)]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df

# Generate the dataset
dataset = generate_dataset()

# Print the dataset
print(dataset)
```

I need a function which can take in a datset like this along with max_number of IDs possible per day. It should move the additional IDs to the next date. And do this for all unique dates. So the output should look something like this, if the max IDs per date is 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will do what you said that you need and you can set the MaxPerDay parameter to whatever value you want:

```
def shiftdates(dataset,MaxPerDay=2):
    #Change the date column to a datetime object
    dataset['Date']=pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'],dayfirst=True)

    NewDatelst=[]
    StartDate=dataset.iloc[0]['Date']
    iterRange=math.floor(len(dataset)/MaxPerDay)
    
    for i in range(iterRange):
        for j in range(MaxPerDay):
            NewDatelst.append(StartDate)
        StartDate=StartDate+np.timedelta64(1, 'D')      
        if i==iterRange-1:
            cleanupIter=len(dataset)-len(NewDatelst)
            for k in range(cleanupIter):
                NewDatelst.append(StartDate)
                
    
    NewDataSet=pd.DataFrame({'Date':NewDatelst,'ID':list(dataset['ID'])})
    
    return NewDataSet
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, get the [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) date, then add days generated with [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) + floor division + [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), optionally converted back to strings with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
import numpy as np

df = generate_dataset()

N = 2 # max number per day

df['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True).min()
              +pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(len(df))//N, unit='D')
             ).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Output:

```
          Date     ID
0   09-03-2024   ID_1
1   09-03-2024   ID_2
2   10-03-2024   ID_3
3   10-03-2024   ID_4
4   11-03-2024   ID_5
5   11-03-2024   ID_6
6   12-03-2024   ID_7
7   12-03-2024   ID_8
8   13-03-2024   ID_9
9   13-03-2024  ID_10
10  14-03-2024  ID_11
```

Intermediates:

```
          Date     ID   datetime  arange  //2 timedelta datetime+timedelta    strftime
0   09-03-2024   ID_1 2024-03-09       0    0    0 days         2024-03-09  09-03-2024
1   09-03-2024   ID_2 2024-03-09       1    0    0 days         2024-03-09  09-03-2024
2   10-03-2024   ID_3 2024-03-10       2    1    1 days         2024-03-10  10-03-2024
3   10-03-2024   ID_4 2024-03-10       3    1    1 days         2024-03-10  10-03-2024
4   11-03-2024   ID_5 2024-03-11       4    2    2 days         2024-03-11  11-03-2024
5   11-03-2024   ID_6 2024-03-11       5    2    2 days         2024-03-11  11-03-2024
6   12-03-2024   ID_7 2024-03-12       6    3    3 days         2024-03-12  12-03-2024
7   12-03-2024   ID_8 2024-03-12       7    3    3 days         2024-03-12  12-03-2024
8   13-03-2024   ID_9 2024-03-13       8    4    4 days         2024-03-13  13-03-2024
9   13-03-2024  ID_10 2024-03-13       9    4    4 days         2024-03-13  13-03-2024
10  14-03-2024  ID_11 2024-03-14      10    5    5 days         2024-03-14  14-03-2024
```